# Why does position: relative use top to shift down and bottom to shift up?

Tags: css, css-position

Why does CSS `position: relative;` use `bottom` to shift up, use `top` to shift down, `left` to shift right, and `right` to shift left?

**Fiddle**: [click me](https://jsfiddle.net/op0gok3s/)

Am I using `position: relative;` incorrectly, or is this some sort of terminology I was not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position
[find out more about the position property here (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Also, you can use negative numbers as well so to shift the element left 20px you could use:

```
left:-20px
```

Answer (score 0):

It's some "terminology I was not aware of", to put it in your own words. When you specify one of those values, you're specifying how far you should move it *away* from that side. So, when you specify a `top:10px`, for example, you're saying "move it 10px away from the top". I think you just had the misunderstanding that you thought it moved towards that side, but it's not exactly how it works. And this isn't just for `position:relative` either, it is also the same in `absolute`, `fixed`, and whatever other position values there are

Answer (score 0):

Its working properly. Please read this article http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent but please try to change position value ex `20,30,40 instead of 10`

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, first let's look at the `position: relative` property/value.

Taken straight from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp):

> An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position.
>
> Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted **away** from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

One way to understand this is, when you set a property like `left` to an element with `relative` positioning, the value you set is how far **away** from it's normal position it will be. So, setting `left` to have a value of `20px` moves it *20px away* from it's normal `left` position. A positive integer will move it to the *right* and a negative will move to the *left*. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLcwbvvd/)

Or, better put by w3schools:

> For relatively positioned elements, the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right to its normal position.

My above description is probably not vernacularly correct, but it helped me understand it in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply it positions the element x amount of pixels from the direction specified.